# Add toolbar - error "no object added"

Tags: arcgis-9.3, toolbar

I'm trying to add Hawths Tools to by Toolbar selection.  I'm running ArcMap/ArcInfo v.9.3.1. Hawths Tools is not supported in v.10.  I've dowloaded the zip file, extracted the files, adn ran teh .exe file.  When I go to "customize" Tools, add from file, and select under Program files "HawthsTools3.dll", an "Added Objects..." menu pops up that reads: No new objects added.

If you then open ArcMap, select View, then Toolbars, Hawths Tools does not show up.

Can anyone provide assistance?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are heaps of things which can result in "No new objects added". However as you are installing someone else's work rather than developing it should be more straightforward. First, try selecting the .tlb file instead of the .dll. If this doesn't work I can expand with other suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

You should register HawthsTools by double clicking HawthsTools3 Registration entries..and then...follow the procedure that you been done...